# Dealing with MLMultiArray from MLModel

Tags: ios, swift, object-detection, coreml, mlmodel

I'm using a `mlmodel` in my project to detect objects. The input for model is `Image (Color 300 x 300)` and outputs are `MultiArray (Double)` and `MultiArray (Double 4 x 1917 x 1)`. I did `VNCoreMLRequest` and I got the output is exact as mentioned above. Here, I need to show the object name and confidence to the user from `MLMultiArray` output. Now, the question is how to decode it, how to get object name and confidence from the `MLMultiArray`. I'm researching from past 3 days and no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 1917 tells me you're most likely using MobileNet + SSD.

I wrote a number of blog posts that explain how this sort of thing works. Here is a blog post that explains how to do the decoding for MobileNetV2+SSDLite, but the same logic works for other versions of MobileNet and SSD as well: https://machinethink.net/blog/mobilenet-ssdlite-coreml/